# Google Cloud workflow with cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-workflows

We are making few changes to the present architecture and want to implement Google cloud workflow which will track the flow of a project creation. All the handlers are placed in Cloud Run. Now, how can I call the specific end points in the Workflow from Cloud Run??

I only have one cloud Run URL? I am new to Cloud. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to call a  Cloud Run specific endpoint from Workflow? Are you able to curl this Cloud Run endpoint URL for now?

Answer (score -1):

To summarize if you want to - Use Workflows with Cloud Run and Cloud Functions. Please have look to this - [here](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/run/tutorial-cloud-run)

Just to refer, below are the abstracted steps from above for you as an example, to give you an idea, where you have to create a single workflow, connecting one service at a time:

1. Deploy two Cloud Functions services: the first function generates a
   random number, and then passes that number to the second function
   which multiplies it.
2. Using Workflows, connect the two HTTP functions
   together. Execute the workflow and return a result that is then
   passed to an external API.
3. Using Workflows, connect an external HTTP
   API that returns the log for a given number. Execute the workflow
   and return a result that is then passed to a Cloud Run service.
4. Deploy a Cloud Run service that allows authenticated access only.
   The service returns the math.floor for a given number.
5. Using Workflows, connect the Cloud Run service, execute the entire
   workflow, and return a final result.

An excerpt, to give you as an example (from above reference), to create a Cloud Run service based on a container and invoke/attach it to in Workflows...

Build the container image:

```
export SERVICE_NAME=<your_svc_name>
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/${SERVICE_NAME}
```

Deploy the container image to Cloud Run, ensuring that it only accepts authenticated calls:

```
gcloud run deploy ${SERVICE_NAME} \
--image gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/${SERVICE_NAME} \
--platform managed \
--no-allow-unauthenticated
```

When you see the **service URL**, the deployment is complete. You will need to specify that URL when updating the workflow definition.

Create a text file with the filename e.g. "workflows.yaml" with the following content:

```
- randomgen_function:
    call: http.get
    args:
        url: https://us-central1-*****.cloudfunctions.net/randomgen
    result: randomgen_result
- multiply_function:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: https://us-central1-*****.cloudfunctions.net/multiply
        body:
            input: ${randomgen_result.body.random}
    result: multiply_result
- log_function:
    call: http.get
    args:
        url: https://api.mathjs.org/v4/
        query:
            expr: ${"log(" + string(multiply_result.body.multiplied) + ")"}
    result: log_result
- floor_function:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: https://**service URL**
        auth:
            type: OIDC
        body:
            input: ${log_result.body}
    result: floor_result
- return_result:
    return: ${floor_result}
```

Note: here you replace **service URL** with your Cloud Run service URL generated above.

This connects the Cloud Run service in the workflow. Note that the auth key ensures that an authentication token is being passed in the call to the Cloud Run service.

Deploy the workflow, passing in the service account:

```
cd ~
gcloud workflows deploy <<your_workflows_name>> \
--source=workflow.yaml \
--service-account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Execute the workflow:

```
gcloud workflows run <<your_workflows_name>>
```

The output should resemble the following:

```
result: '{"body":............;
...
startTime: '2021-05-05T14:36:48.762896438Z'
state: SUCCEEDED
```